# Problem with final branch in a parallel activity

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, workflow-foundation, infopath

This might seem like a silly thing to say, the final branch in a parallel activity so I'll clarify. It's a parallel activity with three branches each containing a simple create task, on task changed and complete task. The branch containing the task that is last to complete seems to break. So every task works in it's own right, but the last one encounters a problem.

Say the user clicks the final tasks link to open the attached infopath form and submits that. Execution gets to the event handler for that onTaskChanged where a taskCompleted variable gets set to true which will exit the while loop. I've successfully hit a breakpoint on this line so I know that happens. However the final activity in that branch, the completeTask doesn't get hit.

When submit is clicked in the final form, the operation in progess screen says of for quite a while before returning to the workflow status page. The task that was opened and submitted says "Not Started".

I can disable any of the branches to leave only two, but the same problem happens with the last to be completed. Earlier on in the workflow I do essencially the same thing. I have another 3 branch parallel activity with each brach containing a task. This one works correctly **which leads me to believe that it might be a problem with having two parallel activites in the same sequential workflow**.

I've considered the possibility that it might be a correlation token problem. The token that every task branch uses is unique to that branch and it's owner activity name is est to that of the branch. It stands to reason that if the task complete variable is indeed getting set to true but the while loop isn't being exited, then there's a wire crossing with the variable somewhere. However I'd still have thought that the task status back on the workflow status page would at least say that the task is in progress.

This is a frustrating show stopper of a bug for me. Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appricated so I can investigate them.

Comment: Dan, this may be unfair to ask after so long, but how did you get the OnTaskChanged into the same parallel activity as the createTask? I get an error StateInitializationActivity cannot contain activities that implement 'System.Workflow.Activities.IEventActivity'.

I am assuming you are using a state machine workflow ...

Comment: I believe I put the various task activities inside a sequence activity which I then placed inside the parallel branch.

Answer (score 0):

my workflow scenario is to reassign task to it's originator after due date of the task expires, by firing a delay activity.
in my workflow I have a **parallel** replicator which is used to assign(create) different tasks to different users at the same time.Inside replicator I used a listen activity so in the left branch there is a OnTaskChanged activity+...+ completetask1, In the right branch of listenActivity there is a **Delay Activity** followed by a **CompleteTask2 activity** and a code activity to reassign task to task originator.I'm sure about the correlation tokens on both completetasks activities.every thing works fine on the left branch but error occurs in the right branch which contains Delay activity-->Completetask activity.
let consider that we have two tasks assigned to 2 users and they have one hour to complete their tasks, but they didn't.so Delay activity fires for both tasks.then in workflow first task will be completed but for the second task it makes error.

I think the problem is with taskid property of the completetask.it doesn't updated with the second task id, so it tries to complete a task which has been completed.